# Select option can't be clicked in firefox in modal panel

Tags: asp.net, firefox, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an Ajax modal panel with select inside. When I want to change selected value in Firefox nothing happens. I already tried a trick with autocomplete attribute on select with no success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I did it. It was caused by PopupDragHandleControlID attribute which was set to whole panel. True thing is that it should be associated with header but if someone wants drag anywhere on the panel this bug can appear.